# Laravel Homestead: web page reads 'no input file specified'

Tags: laravel, homestead

Already read through several posts, but did not find the answer.
My problem is the page of my laravel site only reads input file not found.
This is after going through installing laravel using the manual.
I gather I was in the wrong directory at some stage, as I discovered that I do not have a .homestead directory in my root directory. Instead it is located in the Users/myname/ directory.

I am not sure how to proceed from here.
Should I do a new install and if so, what should I remove first?

Thanks.

Comment: Make sure homestead's ngix is looking in project/public where the laravel index.php file should be.

Comment: I have edited this already in the sites-enabled folder to point to my users/myname/Code/laravel/public folder

Comment: Show your hosts files on host machine and on virtual machine

Answer (score 0):

Not quite yet, there are a few reasons I can think of. Have you ran all of these commands inside Homestead > Your project root

1. composer install
2. npm install
3. did you copy your .env.example into a .env file
4. does your .env have a APP_KEY value (use "php artisan key:generate" to automatically add it)

Comment: don'te forget provision

Comment: I have a folder called Homestead in my home directory (I am on a mac) - my user directory. Inside this Homestead folder there is no project, just the homestead 
files. My project is located elsewhere: in the same home directory in the file Code.  

home dir / Homestead  
home dir/ Code / laravel /

Comment: 1.In your homestead folder, have you edited the homestead.yml folder to reflect your project location? 2.have you then ran "vagrant up --provision" to turn the virtual machine on.  3. You can then enter your virtual machine using "vagrant ssh" its a full Linux machine in there pre installed will everything you will need for laravel

Comment: 1. Yes my homestead yaml:
folders:
    - map: ~/Code
      to: /Users/username/Code

sites:
    - map: homestead.local
      to: /Users/username/Code/laravel/public
2. Yes done that. but getting notification that I am running composer as root while it is owned by vagrant. And: you are already using composer version 1.8.5

3.

Comment: 3. yes got into vagrant ssh.

4. it is working!! Do I need to do vagrant ssh everytime?

Comment: Have you added an entry to your operating systems Host file so it recognizes the homestead.yml custom url (in this case homestead.local ). In the event that this is the only hosted service on your computer, you can likely access it by going to http://localhost/ instead of homestead.local.

Comment: Glad to hear it is working now, no you do not have to do the ssh command every time, as long as the instance is running ("vagrant up" or "vagrant up --provision" if you edit the homestead.yml file) you will be in business. Happy coding!